# SQL: Create new columns for records with multiple results?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Sorry if this question is confusing, but I wasn't sure how else to word it. I'm currently working on a query where I have a list of patients at a medical facility who have certain diagnosis codes. It's a pretty basic query:

```
SELECT [several patient demographic fields]
FROM Diagnosis
WHERE DiagnosisCode IN (a bunch of diagnosis codes)
```

The query itself works fine, but there are a number of patients who have multiple codes from the WHERE clause attached to their chart, and each code ends up on a new row, so I get multiple results for each patient, with the code as the only difference, like so:

```
PatientID    Name             DiagnosisCode
------------------------------------------------
1001         John Smith       123.0
1001         John Smith       ABC.0
1002         Jane Doe         456.1
1003         Bob Brown        789.0
1003         Bob Brown        DEF.1
1003         Bob Brown        XYZ.0
```

I can work with this easily enough, but I wanted to know if there was any possible way to code this query so that a new column was created for every individual record for a given patient, thus displaying the results like this:

```
PatientID    Name             DxCode1     DxCode2     DxCode3
--------------------------------------------------------------
1001         John Smith       123.0       ABC.0
1002         Jane Doe         456.1
1003         Bob Brown        789.0       DEF.1       XYZ.0
```

The problem is that I have no way of knowing initially how many results a given patient is going to have. It *looks* like the majority of people only have 2 or 3, but in theory, a patient could have every diagnosis code included in my WHERE clause. In that case, that would be a LOT of added columns, but I would need SQL Server to just look at how many results there were for that patient and add those columns accordingly, if that makes sense.

Anyway, this is more of a curiosity question than a I-need-this-answered-in-order-to-even-do-my-work question. Would something like this even be possible?

Comment: I would create a different table which will contain different diagnosis and their types then a table to record patients and diagnosis they have. I think creating columns per diagnosis code would at some point exhaust the columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to perform a dynamic `PIVOT` but also to create the column names. Something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE #DataSource
(
    [PatientID] INT
   ,[Name] VARCHAR(12)
   ,[DiagnosisCode] VARCHAR(12)
   ,[ColumName] VARCHAR(12)
);

INSERT INTO #DataSource ([PatientID], [Name], [DiagnosisCode], [ColumName])
SELECT [PatientID]
      ,[Name]
      ,[DiagnosisCode]
      ,'DxCode' + CAST(DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY [PatientID] ORDER BY [DiagnosisCode]) AS VARCHAR(6))
FROM 
(
    VALUES (1001, 'John Smith', '123.0')
          ,(1001, 'John Smith', 'ABC.0')
          ,(1002, 'Jane Doe', '456.1')
          ,(1003, 'Bob Brown', '789.0')
          ,(1003, 'Bob Brown', 'DEF.1')
          ,(1003, 'Bob Brown', 'XYZ.0')
) DS ([PatientID], [Name], [DiagnosisCode]);

DECLARE @DynammicTSQLStatement NVARCHAR(MAX)
       ,@DynamicPIVOTColumns NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @DynamicPIVOTColumns = STUFF
                            (
                                (
                                SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME([ColumName])
                                FROM #DataSource
                                GROUP BY [ColumName]
                                ORDER BY [ColumName]
                                FOR XML PATH('') ,TYPE
                                ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
                                ,1
                                ,1
                                ,''
                            );


SET @DynammicTSQLStatement = N'
SELECT *
FROM #DataSource DS
PIVOT
(
    MAX([DiagnosisCode]) FOR [ColumName] IN (' + @DynamicPIVOTColumns + ')
) PVT';


EXEC sp_executesql @DynammicTSQLStatement

DROP TABLE #DataSource;
```

[image]

Comment: Oooooo nice! I'll probably just stuck with the way I'm doing it for now but I imagine something like this will come in handy in the future